# Rename Files to Same Filename Without Extension with find Command

Tags: find, filenames, cp

I'd like to rename a group of files to their same filename but without extension. They are scattered in my home directory and I don't know where they are located precisely, but I do know the extension to be removed.

I need to have one and only one command to perform this task.

Here's the partial command:

```
$ find ~/ -type f -name "*.hhs" -exec mv {} <I DO NOT KNOW> \;
```

Where `<I DO NOT KNOW>` is to be replaced by your suggestion. For example, I tried to replace it with the following:

```
`basename {} .hhs`
```

It does not work for me.

---

**Example**

If files `file1.jpg.hhs` and `file2.jpg.hhs` are found, I'd like them to be renamed as follows: `file1.jpg` and `file2.jpg`

Comment: why do you need only one command? I'm curious.

Comment: Your `find` example uses `cp` , which would create a *copy* yet your title and body of the question imply a *rename* -- what's the goal?

Comment: My apologies, I corrected the title.

Comment: The reason why I want everything under one command: for the beauty. I like to condense. Why creating a multiline script with variables while my task could be solved under one command only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have or can install the PERL extension, `rename` (`apt-get install rename` on a Debian-based distribution)...

```
find ~ -type f -name "*.hhs" -exec rename -d ".hhs" {} +
```

The option, `-d` or `--delete` deletes the specified string.

Answer (score 1):

You require a tool that can delete the `.hhs` filename suffix from the filename.  `find` can not do this for you, so you will have to call another utility through `-exec`:

```
find "$HOME" -type f -name '*.hhs' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        cp -i "$pathname" "${pathname%.hhs}"
    done' sh {} +
```

I'm not using `basename` here as that would also remove the directory path from the found pathnames (which could be inserted again with `dirname`, but it would yield messy code).

Instead, I call an in-line shell script with as many found pathnames as possible, and let the script loop over these, copying the individual files.  The new name is constructed using a standard parameter substitution that deletes the string `.hhs` from the end of the value of `$pathname`.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Noted.

Comment: +1 Great method, @Kusalananda :-) Please explain how the shellscript works in this case: how is `pathname` given its value? What is the difference compared to `find . -name "*.pdf" -exec bash -c 'echo cp -p "$1" "${1%%.pdf}"' bash {} \;` which works for me (I tested locally and for pdf files).

Comment: @sudodus I hoped to avoid that explanation by linking to a more expressive general answer regarding the various uses of `-exec` with `find`.  But in general, `find` passes the found pathnames to the utility that you call from `-exec`, replacing `{}` with the pathname that it has found. With `-exec ... {} +`, `find` will replace `{}` with not _one_ pathname, but with _as many as possible_.  This means that the script that I have is called with a number of pathnames, and the loop in the script loops over these.

Comment: @sudodus In your example with `bash`, the `bash` shell will be invoked once for each file.  This is slow if there are many files.

Comment: Thanks. But one more question. I have learned that a shellscript will use `$1` etc as parameters. How come you can use `pathname` for this purpose? Will the first available variable be used in these cases?

Comment: @sudodus I'm looping over the positional parameters with `for pathname do`. `$pathname` will be the value of `$1`, then `$2`, and `$3` etc.